# How should i document the parameter "says"?

Tags: java, javadoc

Can't resolve the problem :\ How i should document the second parameter "says"? Because SonarQube asking me about this again and again.

```
public class Dogs {

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Dogs.class);
    private final String                  name;
    private final String                  says;

    /**
     * The Dogs class.
     *
     * @param name
     *            says. // here the problem
     *
     */
    public Dogs(final String name, final String says) {
        this.name = name;
        this.says = says;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should add @param in front of the param name, like this :

```
/**
 * The Dogs class.
 *
 * @param name explain what is it ! 
 * @param says explain what is it !
 *
 */
public Dogs(final String name, final String says) {
    this.name = name;
    this.says = says;
}
```